# Accessing phonegap view for the second time does not work

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, controller, phonegap

I am building a phone gap application and have a results page (accessed from various different locations).

This page carries out logic in its controller and then uses

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#table')).append($compile(tableHTML)$scope));
```

to fill the table with the generated HTML.

Accessing this once works, however when I access this again it carries out the logic etc, but leaves a blank page. Any ideas please?

Comment: Your access again is reloading page or left page, then come later ?

Comment: First I go on the results page, then I access the results page from somewhere else. The second time round, it does not need to work